# How to get column values which are changed after groupby applied?

Tags: java, apache-spark, aggregate-functions

I am working on a spark code using java  , where after join condition we got multiple records because of duplicate `IDs` in different sources,(`ID` are duplicates but some attribute changed) so with same id we have multiple records.what I need is to combine which are duplicates records to on single unique row for each `ID`

**Input Dataset**

```
+---+---+---+----+---+---+
|id |b  |c  |d   |f  |g  |
+---+---+---+----+---+---+
|1  |e  |dd |ddd |34 |r5t|
|1  |e  |dd2|ddd |34 |r5t|
|1  |e  |dd3|ddd |34 |rt |
|2  |e  |dd |ddd1|34 |5rt|
|4  |e  |dd |ddd1|34 |rt |
|1  |e  |dd4|ddd |34 |rt |
|4  |e  |dd4|ddd |34 |rt |
|4  |e  |dd4|ddd |3  |rt |
|2  |e  |dd |ddd |3  |r5t|
|2  |e  |dd |ddd |334|rt |
+---+---+---+----+---+---+
```

**expected output**

```
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
|id |f             |            b |             g|d                  |d             |
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
|1  |[34]          |[e]           |[r5t, rt]     |[dd4, dd3, dd2, dd]|[ddd]         |
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

I tried giving explicitly `collect_list` as below

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(


                 functions.collect_set("f"),
                 functions.collect_set("b")

                ).show(1,false);
```

But my case we have 300 columns, in the dataset that too columns may not be same, changing some times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark `org.apache.spark.sql` package, there is `agg(exprs: Map[String, String])` method which accepts a `Map<String,String>` where `key` is name of column and value is sql.functions.

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true")
                .load("...");

Map<String,String> collect_MAP =  Arrays.stream(df.columns())
            .filter(f -> !f.equals("id"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f,f -> "collect_set"));


     df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_MAP).show(false);
```

**result**

```
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
|id |collect_set(f)|collect_set(b)|collect_set(g)|collect_set(c)     |collect_set(d)|
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
|1  |[34]          |[e]           |[r5t, rt]     |[dd4, dd3, dd2, dd]|[ddd]         |
|4  |[3, 34]       |[e]           |[rt]          |[dd4, dd]          |[ddd1, ddd]   |
|2  |[334, 3, 34]  |[e]           |[r5t, rt, 5rt]|[dd]               |[ddd1, ddd]   |
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
```